# elm.children is not a function (inside $('.input-group').each

Tags: jquery

How to access **multiple** childrens of element in **jQuery** ??

for short:

```
$('.input-group').each(function(i, elm)
{
  elm.children('.input-group-addon').addClass('alert-danger'); // <-- elm.children is not a function
  elm.children('.form-control').first().text('aaa bbb ccc');   // <-- elm.children is not a function
});
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) callback refers to a standard [`Element`](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element) object, **not** a jQuery object. You can wrap the element in `$(...)` to enable the use of jQuery methods:

```
let $elm = $(elm);
$elm.children('.input-group-addon').addClass('alert-danger');
$elm.children('.form-control').first().text('aaa bbb ccc');
```

```js
$('.input-group').each(function(i, elm)
{
  let $elm = $(elm);
  $elm.children('.input-group-addon').addClass('alert-danger');
  $elm.children('.form-control').first().text('aaa bbb ccc');
});
```

```css
.alert-danger { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
</div>
```

---

Or use `$(this)`:

```
let $elm = $(this);
$elm.children('.input-group-addon').addClass('alert-danger');
$elm.children('.form-control').first().text('aaa bbb ccc');
```

```js
$('.input-group').each(function(){
  let $elm = $(this);
  $elm.children('.input-group-addon').addClass('alert-danger');
  $elm.children('.form-control').first().text('aaa bbb ccc');
});
```

```css
.alert-danger { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
</div>
```

---

That said, it doesn't seem like a use-case for a loop, and it's often better to avoid them where possible. Instead I might suggest something like the following:

```js
$('.input-group')
  .children('.input-group-addon')
  .addClass('alert-danger')
  .end()
  .children('.form-control:first')
  .text('aaa bbb ccc');
```

```css
.alert-danger { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="input-group-addon">Addon</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
  <div class="form-control">Form Control</div>
</div>
```

The snippet above narrows down the selection to `.children('.input-group-addon')`, and then uses [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) to refer back to the initial selection of `.input-group`.

> #### `.end()`
>
> **Description:** End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

Comment: .end() is new for me!

Comment: @MisterJojo It can be very useful! I can explain a bit more if you'd like.

Comment: @TylerRoper: You can use "this" as context while searching for child elements, Will save couple of lines I guess. Eg:  $('.input-group-addon',this)

Comment: @MuraliNepalli That's true. OP, if you decide to go with the `this` approach, I would suggest using the suggestion in Murali's answer. It saves you a line and skips the unnecessary cast to jQuery object :)

Comment: First, I learn more with your answer, even if I run the risk of using the Murali solution

Answer (score 1):

In your loop use "this" as context to search child elemnts instead of "elm".
In this way you need not to convert "elm" to jquery object $(elm)

```
$('.input-group').each(function(i, elm) {
  $('.input-group-addon',this).addClass('alert-danger'); 
  $('.form-control',this).first().text('aaa bbb ccc');   
});
```

Comment: but I like it ;)